# Upgrade magento 1.5.1 to Magento 2.3x

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento-1.7, database

Please how do i upgrade my website from Magento 1.5.1.0 to Magento 2.3x

Detailed steps of how to go about it will be appreciated

Comment: Thanks but it isnt what i asked for... you gave me upgrade magento 2.1.6 to 2.1.9?... I asked for Magento 1.5x to magento 2.3x

Comment: Sure but i need the M1.5x  -->>> M2.3x

Comment: Let me know if it will not solve.

Comment: @LoudHouseFamily, did you get my point given in answer ?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to direct migrate form Magento 1.5.1.0 to 2.3.x **because** when you install migration tool you will get minimum version is 1.6.0.0.

> I suggest you to first upgrade to 1.9.4.3 and then migrate to magento
>   2.3.x

please follow magento 2 migration documentations:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

magento versions available for migration:

[image: magento versions available for migration]

Comment: this is correct answer,

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to migrate from M1 to M2 :

**1)** Install blank Magento 2 version

**2)** Update your composer using this command : **composer update**

**3)** After complete composer update process run below command

```
composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool
```

**4)** Go to M2 root directory and execute this below command :

```
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.3.0
```

**2.3.0** => Add your M2 version in which you want to migrate.

This command will copy migration tool at `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool`

**5)** Change file name

From

```
vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/<your m1 version>/config.xml.dist
```

to

```
vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/<your m1 version>/config.xml
```

now, find below code in **config.xml** file and set replace your database details.

```
<source>
    <database host="127.0.0.1" name="magento1" user="root" password="pass"/>
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="127.0.0.1" name="magento2" user="root" password="pass"/>
</destination>
```

**6)** Find **crypt_key** from M1 **app/etc/local.xml** and paste in **config.xml**

```
<crypt_key>your crypt key</crypt_key>
```

Now, execute this below commands :

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/<your M1 version>/config.xml

php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/<your M1 version>/config.xml
```

**ce-to-ce =>** M1 ce version to M2 ce version.

You need change as per your requirements.

Comment: shall i use it for upgrade 1.9.2.3 to 2.3.3? @Rohan Hapani

Comment: Yes. You can...

Comment: this is wrong and confusing answer.

Comment: What's wrong in that?

Comment: @RohanHapani Could you pls explain 4th step?

Comment: In my localhost, I have two versions of Magento like m1 & m2.

Comment: after run composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.3.3
what i need to do in my m1?

Comment: Nothing to do in M1. After that you need to follow 5th step.

Comment: Replace your M1 and M2 database name there in name attribute.

Comment: It would be great if you ask separate question. It will be helpful for others to solve their problem.

Comment: Done everything,,finally https://snipboard.io/sE9u2I.jpg

Comment: Successfully completed after update --auto instead of --reset.

Comment: What is this error => https://snipboard.io/957Kvq.jpg integrity check failed. any help?

Comment: Please ask separate question instead of add new comments of your issue. It would be better for other developers also.

Comment: My account some issue, i can't able to post, can i get help?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to upgrade magento 1.5.1 to 2.3. Migration tool providing upgrade magento 1.6.0.0 to magento 2.2.7.
magento 2.2.7 is last version where you can migrate your version.